# Does Laravel Input::hasfile() work on input arrays?

Tags: file-upload, input, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project that uses a form with multiple file inputs. If I submit the form with the first input  empty and all other inputs with a file, then hasFile returns false. It will only return true if the first input contains a file.

```
if(Input::hasfile('file'))
{
 // do something
}
```

This is the input array via Input::file('file). The small image input is empty, but the large is not. I'd like it to look at the whole array and if there any files present, then proceed with the "do something".

```
Array
(
    [small] => 
    [large] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image_name.jpg
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 44333
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpHILgX2
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpHILgX2
        )

)
```

Is this expected behavior? Or, should it be looking at the entire array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from source:

```
/**
 * Determine if the uploaded data contains a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasFile($key)
{
    if (is_array($file = $this->file($key))) $file = head($file);

    return $file instanceof \SplFileInfo;
}
```

It seems that it only checks the first one from the array, `head` returns the first item from the array.

Comment: Thanks. I read that, but unfortunately my skills didn't allow me to comprehend. I had a feeling it was working as intended. Just needed confirmation.

Comment: Welcome and hope you get the idea :-)

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Thanks for pointing out head. I wasn't sure what that meant.

Answer (score 17):

You can check by using the array key for example like below :-
HTML Input type File Element :

```
<input type="file" name="your_file_name[]" />
```

Laravel 5 : `$request->hasFile('your_file_name.'.$key)`

Laravel 4.2 : `Input::hasFile('your_file_name.'.$key)`

Comment: It works in Laravel 9.x also. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since I can't comment, seems I'll have to post.

Ronak Shah's answer really should be marked the correct one here, and when I figured out why, it instantly had me saying "Sonnofa--" after 30-40 minutes trying to figure this... "mess" out.

Turns out to use hasFile() on an input array, you need to use **dot notation.**

So (using my own example) instead of

```
$request->hasFile("img[29][file]")
```

it needs to be

```
$request->hasFile("img.29.file")
```

That's certainly an eye-opener, given that PHP and dot notation don't really go together. Input arrays really are problem children.

Answer (score 3):

here is a snippet that may help

```
if(Input::hasFile('myfile')){

    $file = Input::file('myfile');

    // multiple files submitted
    if(is_array($file))
    {
        foreach($file as $part) {
            $filename = $part->getClientOriginalName();
            $part->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        }
    }
    else //single file
    {
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess = Input::file('myfile')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    }

} else {
    echo 'Error: no file submitted.';
}
```

Taken from
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=13291

Comment: the `if(is_array($file))` check is not logical as we already decided in our form in naming the field input field, if it has `[]` at end it will always be an array...

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing (Laravel 8) the `Request` class now supports `array`s for the `hasFile` method, as from the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.php#L143):

```
    /**
     * Determine if the request contains the given file.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string|null  $value
     * @param  string|null  $filename
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasFile($name, $value = null, $filename = null)
    {
        if (! $this->isMultipart()) {
            return false;
        }

        return collect($this->data)->reject(function ($file) use ($name, $value, $filename) {
            return $file['name'] != $name ||
                ($value && $file['contents'] != $value) ||
                ($filename && $file['filename'] != $filename);
        })->count() > 0;
    }
```